# Weird message on terminal after installing ROS Melodic

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, ros

Installing ROS Melodic on my Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS, I followed some instructions for the installation and after that, I started to get this message whenever I start the terminal or change to root via `sudo -s`

```
Reading: command not found
Building: command not found
Reading: command not found
```

How can I solve it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this while installing ROS:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

the solution was to do: `nano /.bashrc` and comment the last lines related to that, then the problem was solved.